# Why does restarting my Wi-Fi router on a schedule cause loss of Internet through my cable modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

So first off I know you will need my logs, but I am not at home currently so that will have to wait.

Recently a tech installed setup with an ARRIS SB8200 paired to a ASUS RT-AC66U B1 Wi-Fi router. This is via Xfinity cable.

Evertyhing is pretty good, except that I have the ASUS router set to restart itself every night at 3:30 AM. It's a setting and just a good measure sort of thing that ASUS recommended, so I do it.

More often than not, my router doesn’t “return,” meaning that it loses connection to the cable modem for lack of a better word. The router often will show a dropped WAN connection and packets just freeze. All devices report lack of internet access.

If I then unplug both devices and replug after 5 seconds, things return to normal pretty quick.

What about doing that reset in the middle of the night is causing everything to go haywire?

Comment: Then don’t reset your router every night at 3:30am. What do you believe doing something so blunt would do? Seems to only be causing you problems and whoever gave you that advice really doesn’t know what they are talking about.

Comment: You don't need to reset the router. I don't even remember when I last reset my own router.

Comment: I have also had this experience. Never had a modem where I could unplug the ethernet cable from it and plug it back in without having to restart it to get internet back. This is effectively what the router restart is doing. (arris and motorola surfboards)

Comment: Any manufacturer that recommends you to restart their product daily must have very little confidence in their programmers' ability to make a robust piece of software. Routers should only be reset when there is a problem. That being said, it must be frustrating to have the internet stop working when the router does reset - and that is another poor design by the modem manufacturer. I've had problems with modems doing that in the past as well. Not too sure what the solution is there.

Comment: @jakegould, that routers firmware is notorious for locking up. It seemed to be a HW issue if I remember correctly, about 2 in 10 would do this out of the box and give off a strange hissing noise from the router when the 5Ghz radio was on. (If the 5ghz radio turned on at all)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Then if it’s a known issue, return it to the manufacturer for exchange. But at this point there is no indication that this particular case something like this is needed. What happens if they router is not reset every night? I bet this is a case of the original poster being overly cautious.

Comment: @JakeGould I am late to the party and just giving my 2 cents worth. OP asked a question about loosing connection to cable box. I understand you want to mention that  'don’t reset your router every night at 3:30am', but that is not in line with what OP had asked. It is not helpful in saying that (although I understand why you mentioned it).

Comment: @Cybex I posted my observation as a comment. I think it is fair to say that a questionable practice is a questionable practice in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These routers were problematic when they were first released.

I believe you have one of the hardware versions that fixed most of the problems from the first iterations.
(that's not to say all the Firmware issues were fixed)

If you are using **ASUS branded firmware**, and haven't already. download the latest official firmware for the device [here.](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AC66U-B1/HelpDesk_BIOS/)

Upload it, and see if it fixes the problem... If not there are other solutions.

- #### Low Tech solution

  [image: mechanical timer]

You can always purchase one of these guys to restart the Arris a minute or so **after the RT-AC66u restarts.** Although i am sure that's not what you want to hear.

---

-

#### High Tech solution:

[image: dd-wrt-66u]

- Download 3rd Party Firmware for the router. There are many Flavors
  out there for this router, but I would recommend either OpenWRT or
  DD-WRT for it. With this router, the differences in firmware come
  down to personal preference.
- Either Firmware will allow you to run a customized bash script on it.
- OpenWRT uses the [Cron and Crontab functionality](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/cron)
- DD-WRT also can make use of Cron or run a script directly from NV-RAM @ boot
- Use either Firmware to [write a basic script](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Useful_Scripts#Automatic_Connection_Repair) that will allow you to DOWN/UP the WAN interface a minute or two after a reboot, or
  force a DHCP Release/Renew on the wan interface by schedule.

---

The Arris data sheet indicates that it will only serve one client on it's lan port. The Asus RT-AC66u technically starts in a emergency Management mode in case of firmware flash failure. Regardless of your programmed IP Addresses in the router, it will start with a reachable IP Address for about 3~5 seconds. (I'm not sure if the Mac addresses of the ports remain the same in this mode). So it could be confusing the Arris to believe another client device is connected untill you disconnect and reconnect the Ethernet cable or reboot. Using a script to repair the connection 15~30 seconds after a reboot should fix this if that's what's causing it.

I should also note, all of my DD-WRT access points have the WAN disabled & firewall disabled. All routing and Switching are handled by other devices. They are extremely stable this way.

Comment: +1 for DD-WRT.  It is worth stating that DD-WRT is extremely robust and does not require to be reset regularly.   I would expect it would be able to able to run indefinitely without being reset, and have a number of ASUS routers set up to do this without any issues.   DD-WRT routers are stable even with routing, switching, firewalling, VPN's, Radius, ssh and printing services running on them.

Comment: @davidgo, unfortunately I haven't had a great experience with the RT-66u's (v1's) running dd-wrt. The v3.0-r41892 firmware seems to be running without any issues, I tried a couple late last year that seemed to be pretty stable also. Thanks for the up, mind if i ask what version dd-wrt you are running on your Asus devices?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart “These routers were problematic when they were first released.” They were released in the fall of 2018. It is now 2020. I doubt the problem still exists. But if it does and it’s a known issue, just return it to the manufacturer for exchange. But at this point there is no indication that this particular case something like this is needed. What happens if they router is not reset every night? I bet this is a case of the original poster being overly cautious.

Comment: @jakegould, you must mean the b1, the original version I believe is from 2012/2013...If it's the original firmware it will slow down and eventually lockup over time,(24/48/72hours?)... Return to supplier is how we handled it, because at the time they hadn't fixed it in the U.S firmware. https://www.pcworld.com/article/262149/asus_rt_ac66u_the_best_802_11ac_router_on_the_market_so_far.html

Comment: @jakegould, even the b1 was receiving awards in 2016?...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I am sorry, but sometimes it’s hard to find a specific creation/release date for hardware. In general, I feel that restarting a router every night is not a solution but rather a problem that should be solved. Either with a firmware upgrade or just returning the device completely. The whole premise of the original poster’s question is just flawed: Their problem is their router that should be fixed.

Comment: @jakegould, no need to apologise. I thought I was losing my mind for a second. (I think I was installing these in 2015?) anyway, I agree this may be a router problem. The problem may just be the emergency Management mode of the ac66u freaking out the Arris. He should definitely update the firmware.

Comment: Great answer, looks like I have some work ahead of me!

Comment: @user3687778, Thanks, if you don't mind. Come back after you resolve this and let us know what solution fixed it for you. ~ Best Regards!